# Selection changes on a GEF GraphicalViewer are not recognized by SelectionListener

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

A PostSelectionListener was added to the current workbench window:

```
getWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().addPostSelectionListener(listener);
```

However, selection changes in a `GraphicalViewer` which is being displayed in a `GraphicalEditor` are not recognized by the above listener even though the graphical viewer was set as the graphical editor's site's `SelectionProvider`:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(getGraphicalViewer());
```

I added an `ISelectionChangedListener` to the graphical viewer directly and its `selectionChanged` method is called every time the selection changes (like it's supposed to be).

Does anyone have an idea what could possibly cause this problem?

Also,

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService().getSelection()
```

always returns the correct selection even though the selection change was not registered by the selection listener mentioned first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem, though I do not know why it is a solution.
The `GraphicalEditor` class sets the viewer as the site's selection provider in the `createPartControl(Composite)` method.
I overwrote this method to configure the viewer by myself, but I did not set the selection provider here, but later on in another method. Changing this somehow solved the problem.